# JsonGetter giving null value

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

In my Spring Boot application I am creating a REST API, which is calling some other external REST API. I created User class, which is a object that is received by my Rest API downloaded from the external API. My user model looks like:

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class User {

        private String fullName;

        private String department;

        @JsonGetter("fullName")
        public String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }

        @JsonSetter("full_name")
        public void setFullName(String fullName) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }

        @JsonGetter("department")
        public String getDepartment() {
            return department;
        }

        @JsonSetter("department")
        public void setDepartment(String department) {
            this.department = department;
        }
}
```

I am using JsonGetter and JsonSetter properties, because I would like to have my json properties in response returned in camelCase, but the properties given in external API are returned with underscore:
External API Response:

```
{
    "full_name": "User A",
    "department": "A",
}
```

My API Response:

```
{
    "fullName": "User A",
    "department": "A",
}
```

And everything seems to be working fine (hitting my API with Postman gives proper responses) until I started to create some Http request tests. In tests I receive assertion error that fullName property is null, while doing the same request in postman is responding with proper responses.
My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class HttpRequestTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnUserFullName() throws Exception {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/users/a",
                User.class)).extracting(User::getFullName)
                .contains("User A");
    }
}
```

My controller method:

```
  @GetMapping("users/{name}")
  public ResponseEntity<User> getSpecificUserByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.exchange(createUriString(name), HttpMethod.GET, entity, User.class);
        return response;
    }
```

Test result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
    Expecting:
     <[null]>
    to contain:
     <["User A"]>
    but could not find:
     <["User A"]>
```

I would appreciate any help with this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

`@JsonSetter("full_name")` expects your API response to contain a property `full_name` during  deserialzation. Since `@JsonGetter("fullName")` converts `full_name` to `fullName`, field `private String fullName;` is never set.

You should change `@JsonSetter("full_name")` to `@JsonSetter("fullName")`.

Comment: But when I will change @JsonSetter("full_name") to @JsonSetter("fullName"), API won't set fullName property with value delivered by external API (I checked it with Postman call).

Comment: So, actually you need to the reverse and replace "fullName" with "full_name"

Answer (score 0):

Let us take an example

Suppose your REST API returns below Object of User class

```
User reponse = new User();
response.setFullName("User A");
response.setDepartment("A");
```

So, when we call your REST API, the JSON response would look like as below

```
{
   "fullName":"User A",
   "department":"A"
}
```

Now, When you pass this JSON to convert into **User** class, Jackson will look for methods with the name ***setFullName*** and ***setDepartment***.

In your test case, something similar is happening,

for code 
`this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/users/a",User.class)`

First, it calls your API to get the **User** object Serialized and then it Deserialized it to **User** class. While Deserializing, it looks for a method named
**setFullName** without any

```
 @Setter
 @JsonProperty
 @JsonAlias
```

annotations 
or will look for any setter method with

```
@Setter("fullName")
@JsonProperty("fullName"),
@JsonAlias("fullName")
```

but in your case, the **fullName** setter is treated as

```
public void setFull_name(String fullName) {
 this.fullName = fullname;
}
```

So, setter for fullName is not found but since you marked your **User** class as

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

hence any exception is not thrown but **fullName** for your Response JSON is ignored, so fullName is never set, which remains null and your Test case is failing.

So, either change your test case or mark your setter with

```
@JsonAlias("fullName")
```

annotation.
i.e. Your User class will look like as below

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User {

    private String fullName;

    private String department;

    @JsonGetter("fullName")
    public String getFullName() {
     return fullName;
    }

    @JsonAlias({"fullName","full_name"})
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
     this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @JsonGetter("department")
    public String getDepartment() {
     return department;
    }

    @JsonSetter("department")
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
     this.department = department;
    }

}
```